# using sqs with php to process requests

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

i currently have a add items to a queue in a  sql table- its quite error prone as processing an item can take between 5 and 35 seconds. i was doing it with a cron job but this seems to be  very wastefulness as the cron job page may time out before every item has been processed or one item may have been half processed and not removed from the queue

i was looking at alternatives to using this method- and came across amazon sqs- is it possible to get sqs to make a http request when a new item is added to the queue?

making single http requests would be a lot less taxing on apache that having it hang while it processes a long request.

Answer (score -1):

In your php script try setting [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to 60 (one minute) or whatever you think would do the job .